# Php Mysql Ajax Insert Multiple row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i used a javascript ajax dynamic html form which can add delete input field series.
and i used php for inserting data but when i want to insert multiple row/data
it's insert into database only the first row means first input field series.

[image]

so please check what problem in my code

here is my html code:

```
<form action="invoice.php" id="invoice-form" method="post"  class="invoice-form" role="form" novalidate>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
                <h1 class="text-center title">AFOJAL MINI MARKAET</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>From,</h2>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows='3' id="companyAddress" placeholder="Your Address"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>

            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>To,</h2>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>

            <input data-loading-text="Saving Invoice..." type="submit" name="invoice_btn" value="Save Invoice" class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-top form-control"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="clientCompanyName" placeholder="Company Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows='3' id="clientAddress" placeholder="Your Address"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="invoiceNo" placeholder="Invoice No">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="invoiceDate" placeholder="Invoice Date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control amountDue" id="amountDueTop" placeholder="Amount Due">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        <div class='text-center'>
            <span>Note: Sample Item No. to Search <b>S1, S2</b></span>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                                    <th width="15%">Product</th>
                                    <th width="38%">Description</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Price</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][pro][]" id="ipro_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][des][]" id="ides_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][price][]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][qty][]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][sub_total][]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5'>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subtotal: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tax: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tax" placeholder="Tax" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tax Amount: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="taxAmount" placeholder="Tax" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Total: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalAftertax" placeholder="Total" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Amount Paid: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amountPaid" placeholder="Amount Paid" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Amount Due: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control amountDue" id="amountDue" placeholder="Amount Due" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

here is my ajax code:

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="pro[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="des[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="sub_total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});

//to check all checkboxes
$(document).on('change','#check_all',function(){
    $('input[class=case]:checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
});

//deletes the selected table rows
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
    $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('#check_all').prop("checked", false); 
    calculateTotal();
});


var prices = ["S24_4620|1961 Chevrolet Impala|32.33"];

//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');

    if(type =='productCode' )autoTypeNo=0;
    if(type =='productName' )autoTypeNo=1;  

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {  
             var array = $.map(prices, function (item) {
                 var code = item.split("|");
                 return {
                     label: code[autoTypeNo],
                     value: code[autoTypeNo],
                     data : item
                 }
             });
             //call the filter here
             response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
            $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
            $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);
            $('#price_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
            $('#total_'+id[1]).val( 1*names[2] );
            calculateTotal();
        }               
    });
});

//price change
$(document).on('change keyup blur','.changesNo',function(){
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");
    qty = $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val();
    price = $('#price_'+id[1]).val();
    if( qty!='' && price !='' ) $('#total_'+id[1]).val( (parseFloat(price)*parseFloat(qty)).toFixed(2) );   
    calculateTotal();
});

$(document).on('change keyup blur','#tax',function(){
    calculateTotal();
});

//total price calculation 
function calculateTotal(){
    subTotal = 0 ; sub_total = 0; 
    $('.totalLinePrice').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '' )subTotal += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    });
    $('#subTotal').val( subTotal.toFixed(2) );
    tax = $('#tax').val();
    if(tax != '' && typeof(tax) != "undefined" ){
        taxAmount = subTotal * ( parseFloat(tax) /100 );
        $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount.toFixed(2));
        sub_total = subTotal + taxAmount;
    }else{
        $('#taxAmount').val(0);
        sub_total = subTotal;
    }
    $('#totalAftertax').val( sub_total.toFixed(2) );
    calculateAmountDue();
}

$(document).on('change keyup blur','#amountPaid',function(){
    calculateAmountDue();
});

//due amount calculation
function calculateAmountDue(){
    amountPaid = $('#amountPaid').val();
    sub_total = $('#totalAftertax').val();
    if(amountPaid != '' && typeof(amountPaid) != "undefined" ){
        amountDue = parseFloat(sub_total) - parseFloat( amountPaid );
        $('.amountDue').val( amountDue.toFixed(2) );
    }else{
        sub_total = parseFloat(sub_total).toFixed(2);
        $('.amountDue').val( sub_total);
    }
}


//It restrict the non-numbers
var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8,46); //Backspace
function IsNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    console.log( keyCode );
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
    return ret;
}

//datepicker
$(function () {
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd-mm-yyyy";
    $('#invoiceDate').datepicker({
        startDate: '-3d',
        autoclose: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inv");
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
 $item_name = $_POST["pro"];
 $item_code = $_POST["des"];
 $item_des = $_POST["qty"];
 $item_price = $_POST["price"];
 $subtotal = $_POST["sub_total"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($item_name); $count++)
 {
  $item_name_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_name[$count]);
  $item_code_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_code[$count]);
  $item_des_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_des[$count]);
  $item_price_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_price[$count]);
  $subtotal_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $subtotal[$count]);
  if($item_name_clean != '' && $item_code_clean != '' && $item_des_clean != '' && $item_price_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO sell(pro, des, qty, price, sub_total) 
   VALUES("'.$item_name_clean.'", "'.$item_code_clean.'", "'.$item_des_clean.'", "'.$item_price_clean.'",  "'.$subtotal_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }

 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error/problem?

Comment: php  insert only first row when i add another input field in html form with jquery and ajax. i need to insert multiple row.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and check that it contains what you expect. You can also insert multiple rows like this (instead of multi query): `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES('first1', 'first2'), ('second1', 'second2')`. However, you should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Not even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is 100% SQl Injection proof.

Comment: Also, do a `var_dump($query)` before you execute it and see what the query looks like.

Comment: Please check https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9MAo.png

Comment: Yes, we saw the screen dump in your question. Please try the suggested things from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX

```
 html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="pro[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="des[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
```

PHP

```
 $item_name = $_POST["pro"];
 $item_code = $_POST["des"];
```

*
These assignments in php appear to be inverted, In ajax the productCode gets the name 'pro'.
 Try replace this in PHP:

```
$item_name = $_POST["des"];
 $item_code = $_POST["pro"];
```

Comment: just i replaced in php but still inserted single row

Answer (score 0):

You not using the same name attribute values when appending new rows. Then make the key invoice an array (see in second and third snippet), because you need to loop over that in your PHP (see 4th snippet).

```
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="pro[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="des[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="sub_total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
```

versus

```
<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][][pro]" id="ipro_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][][des]" id="ides_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][][price]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][][qty]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][][sub_total]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
```

Use the same attribute names when appending a new row:

```
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][][pro]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][][des]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][][price]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][][qty]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][][sub_total]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
```

BTW you can also use clone method to append a copy of a table row.

The PHP script..
In you PHP part i see two things going wrong (apart from missing sql injection prevention). You should be looping through data invoice keys, since those carry the array of rows. Then you should add a semicolon to the sql query to close a statement.

```
if (isset($_POST["data"])) {

    foreach($_POST["data"]["Invoice"] as $item) {

        $item_name = $item["pro"];
        $item_code = $item["des"];
        $item_des = $item["qty"];
        $item_price = $item["price"];
        $subtotal = $item["sub_total"];
        $query = '';

        $item_name_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_name);
        $item_code_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_code);
        $item_des_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_des);
        $item_price_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_price);
        $subtotal_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $subtotal);
        if ($item_name_clean != '' && $item_code_clean != '' && $item_des_clean != '' && $item_price_clean != '') {
            $query .= '
   INSERT INTO sell(pro, des, qty, price, sub_total) 
   VALUES("' . $item_name_clean . '", "' . $item_code_clean . '", "' . $item_des_clean . '", "' . $item_price_clean . '",  "' . $subtotal_clean . '";); 
   ';
        }
    }

    if ($query != '') {
        if (mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) {
            echo 'Item Data Inserted';
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replaced but still inserted single row

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You need to alter both you HTML, javascript and php for it to work.